# Could not execute mail delivery program

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

```
$this->load->model('emailmodel');
$query = $this->emailmodel->get_emails();
$emails = array();
set_time_limit(0);

foreach($query->result() as $u)
{
    $this->notification->send($u->to, $this->config->item('neworder'),'orders/mail/subscription', 
        array(
            'order' => $neworder,
            'user' => $user
        ));
    break;
}
```

so I am sending mail in a loop for each subscribed user, but it gives me an error:

```
Could not execute mail delivery program '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i '
```

how to fix this?

Comment: Does `/usr/sbin/sendmail` exist?

Comment: i can send mails Without the foreach loop, but in the foreach loop it gives me this error, i've tried to increase the memory_limit to 128MB, but it doesn't helped

Comment: Is there other way to send a email to subscribed users without a loop?

Comment: No, using a loop is the right thing. The error is pretty explicit. Something is going wrong when invoking the `sendmail` binary. Can you switch to sending via SMTP instead? SMTP usually gives better error messages. (In fact, invoking `sendmail` with `-t -i` pretty much *turns off* all of the useful error messages...)

Comment: mail type is html, charset: utf-8, what config name => value, shut i pass to switch via smtp?

Comment: i've googled for this error, didn't find anything usefull, is said that its a lack of memory, but've increased it...anyway still geting this error, also i make a break after sending a first email, so in fact i send just one email like if there was no loop, but the error happens only in the foreach loop

Comment: Wow it works on a for loop, but gives me an error in the foreach loop, can't figure out why is that, i just get the user emails from the database and then want to loop it

Comment: Check the data being returned, it almost sounds like some of the data is bad. Also are you running this locally or on a host? If it's a host some don't allow for the changing of php.ini settings from the client.

Comment: Go back to basics. Isolate what data is being sent. Start with 1 loop and increase the send array by 1 until you track down the issue. I agree with @RickCalder that this sounds like bad data is being returned. There is no reason that using `sendmail` in a loop would fail on its own.

Answer (score 2):

I think your system doesn't support sendmail in that path.. You have to change the sendmail path or reinstall it and be sure that your queue mail isnot overloaded...

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem.
please check the security limits on your system (ulimit)

You can execute **ulimit -a**

> bash# ulimit -a
>
> ...
>   open files     (-n) 1024
>   max user processes  (-u) 1024
>   ...

You can change this on RedHat in **/etc/security/limits.conf**
We have change the nproc and nofile to a bigger value.

Because each mail() call opens a port(file). If you reach the Filelimit this errormessage occurs.

Answer (score 0):

We also had this strange error show up all of a sudden. Restarting php-fpm cleared the issue in our case. It may have been caused my the maximum number of files, or some other memory-leak type of issue. To prevent this from happening again, I enabled pm.max_requests = 200 so that the php-fpm processes are cycled more often.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the site was hosted on MediaTemple and it appeared to be the PHP version. The site was running on 5.3 FastCGI and when I switched to 5.3 CGI it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The same case of sending more than 50,000 emails (1.1GB of data) occurred here.

I used a simple script that reads everything with a "select * from email_queue" and passes it to mail() in a mysqli_fetch_assoc()-loop. This has been running smoothly with cronjob for years, but not the last times.

The solution here was to send only a "select id from email_queue", which then reads the record in the loop with another "select *..." and passes it to mail(). Besides, the average load has dropped significantly.